# Mysteries of the ContentType Inherits attribute

Tags: content-type, inheritance

When defining content types in SharePoint 2010, there is a new `Inherits` attribute. According to the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544268.aspx):

> The value of this attribute determines
>   whether the content type inherits
>   fields from its parent content type
>   when it is created.
>
> If Inherits is TRUE, the child content
>   type inherits all fields that are in
>   the parent, including fields that
>   users have added.
>
> If Inherits is FALSE or absent and the
>   parent content type is a built-in
>   type, the child content type inherits
>   only the fields that were in the
>   parent content type when SharePoint
>   Foundation was installed. The child
>   content type does not have any fields
>   that users have added to the parent
>   content type.

I'm finding that whenever `Inherits=FALSE` the content type is deployed internally but can't be seen from the UI. Why is this?

Further to that, what is the point of `Inherits=FALSE` anyway?

Answer (score 2):

This attribute first appeared in the RC version.

I'm not sure of the validity of having a custom content type with:

- an ID which derives from an existing one
- using `Inherits=FALSE`.

I'm also not sure if an appropriate error is raised in this scenario (if it is indeed invalid). In the absence of more detailed documentation, I think the only thing we can conclude is to that if you use `Inherits=TRUE` when creating child content types you'll be fine!

Answer (score 1):

As far as my "investigations" into this attribute goes it doesn´t seem to have much effect when you don´t apply the overwrite attribute (with value TRUE), e.g. it makes no effect if I make it TRUE or FALSE.
However, `if you add the overwrite=TRUE attribute the inherited content type won´t "inherit" any fields from its parent.`

As far as I can tell the `overwrite=TRUE actually tells SP to add the content type via the object model (into the DB) but when set to FALSE the elements.xml on disc will be used.`

It´s a bit confusing but as far as I can see the `"best practice" would be to use Overwrite=TRUE in conjunction with Inherits=TRUE|FALSE otherwise it has no real effect`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this new Attribute is backward compatible with version 3 content type definitions. Inherits=FALSE is how it used to work and Inherits=TRUE is the new way. Does this mean it's no longer necessary to create a correctly formatted ID? Or do you need to follow the format ONLY if Inherits=FALSE.